# How to add a new value to this on click

Tags: javascript, jquery, append, this

Heey everyone,

I am just starting to learn a bit of programming and I am stuck on a small test project.

I want to make it so, that when I click on a chess piece, I can add it into a tile of the board.

With the first piece it works fine, I also can move it around without any trouble.

But when I want to add more pieces, it will add them all into 1 tile of the board.

This var is adding every img I click and not only saving the last one I clicked:

```
var pawnToAdd = this;
```

Here is the piece of code, what am I doing wrong here?

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('img').on('click', function(){
    var pawnToAdd = this;
    console.log(pawnToAdd);

  $('.tile').on('click', function(){
    console.log(this);
    this.append(pawnToAdd);
   });
  });     
});
```

Comment: Please add the relevant HTML and CSS to your question so that we can replicate your issue and provide you with a working answer.

Comment: Every click of an img, is creating a new click event handler on all the tiles.  Don't do that.

Comment: To be a bit more clear, your `.tile` click event code is nested inside of your `img` click handler. Move the `.tile` click code so that it comes after the `img` click code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var pawnToAdd = null;

  $('img').on('click', function() {
    //set the pawn to add
    pawnToAdd = this;
  });
  
  $('.tile').on('click', function() {
    //do nothing if no pawn has been clicked yet
    if (pawnToAdd != null) {
      this.append(pawnToAdd);
      //clear out the pawn reference so the user has to click another one
      pawnToAdd = null;
    }
  });
});
```

Comment: Do you understand the changes?

Comment: Yes I do, only didn't know the correct syntax. I was trying things like pawnToAdd = ""; and a removeData. But this worked :) Thanks again.

Comment: I have one more question. Before the change I could move the pawn from tile to tile. Now I can only add them to the board. But once they are added to a tile I cannot move them. Should I make a new function for this, or can I edit this one so that I can also move the pieces around the board? Since I dont see why that is not possible anymore

Comment: If you want to be able to keep moving them from tile to tile, comment out the `pawnToAdd = null;` part in the click handler.

Comment: That worked, can you explain why that is? Now I also dont fully get the previous change...

Comment: Setting the value to null makes it lose reference to the pawn you had selected.  By commenting that out, it doesn't lose reference and it will repeat the logic with the same pawn until you choose a new one.

Comment: But why did it not lose the slected img once I selected a new one with my original code and now it does?

Comment: Because I put that `pawnToAdd = null;` in the click handler to clear out the variable, as I was guessing that you'd want the user to choose another pawn to set on the board after each time.  If that's not the case, as you've suggested, that line can be removed.

Comment: Okey, now I see it. There is a new var before the click handler. I now understand what happens and why my code did not work. Thank you for the help and time :)